# Facelets Template: Component ID * has already been found in the view

Tags: jsf, facelets

I want to use a template in which his header is always the same header, and the content is changing by every page I'm trying to load.

here's the code of commonLayout.xhtml' body:

```
<h:body>

<div id="page">

    <div id="header">
        <ui:insert name="header">
            <ui:include src="/rs/upperTabs/adminXHTML.xhtml" />
        </ui:insert>
    </div> 

    <div id="content">
        <ui:insert name="content" >
            <ui:include src="/rs/common/commonContent.xhtml" />
        </ui:insert>
    </div>  
</div>

</h:body>
```

and this is the planting content's code in every page of my app:

```
<ui:composition template="/rs/common/commonLayout.xhtml">
<ui:define name="content">...</ui:define></ui:composition>
```

When I open a second page or refresh the first page I get the following error in the log:

> ERROR | 2015-02-10 02:35:28,955 | http-bio-8080-exec-15  | JSP Error page Component ID adminPanelBar:menuItems:j_idt149 has already been found in the view.    |
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component ID adminPanelBar:menuItems:j_idt149 has already been found in the view.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Please, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Are you dealing with `binding` (in other than a request scoped bean) or some JSTL stuff like `<c:forEach>` to generate some components within a loop somewhere on `adminXHTML.xhtml` or `commonContent.xhtml` including the page contents itself? Unlike `<ui:repeat>`, `<c:forEach>` does not prepend ids with an iterating index.